# If $\beth_1$ is weakly inaccessible, are any of the cardinal characteristics of continuum provably strictly less than $\beth_1$?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Assume ZFC+"$\beth_1$ is weakly inaccessible." Are there any cardinal characteristics of the continuum mentioned at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum) that can thereby be proved to have cardinality strictly less than $\beth_1$?

Comment: Whoa. There are _other_ Hebrew letters in math?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: There's also $\gimel$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, see [beth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number). For example, the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\beth_1$, the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ are $\beth_2$, etc.

Comment: @goblin As a Hebrew speaker, seeing it spelled "beth" is really weird. (In Modern Hebrew, it's pronounced "bet." Actually (assuming you're reading dotted Hebrew), without a dot in the middle, it's "vet.")

Comment: @columbus8myhw, so I should be saying "vet 1"?

Comment: @goblin No, "bet 1." This isn't dotted Hebrew, and if it's un-dotted you usually assume it's "bet." However, seeing as this is not actually the Hebrew language, I think that "beth" would be better. (Kind of like how the Greeks pronounce $\beta$ "veta" but we don't.)

Comment: @goblin A side note: "Beth" is more historically accurate (if you go far back enough).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, assuming that theory is consistent. Martin's Axiom is known to imply that all those cardinal characteristics go to the top, with value continuum, but it is consistent with MA that the continuum is weakly inaccessible, since one may undertake the usual forcing of MA of length an inaccessible cardinal.